# Setting up remote access for mysql on bluehost

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to set up and host a db on Bluehost but having issues when testing it locally. Setting connection string as `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname")`
`
but I keep getting "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it".

I should note that I'm setting the database as a remote connection.

Comment: have you read your hosts instructions on how to do this? https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/89

Comment: Yes, I referenced the instructions

Answer (score 0):

It seems permission is granted, try to grant the permission first. Here "%" mean Db can accept the connection from any IP, if you want to make DB can accept the connection from specific hostname for IP then instead of "%" use the hostname or IP.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'%';
```

Comment: Yes, now when I attempt this query I receive the response: `"success:false" "you should upgrade to mysql 5.5 or later"`

But when I check the version used it is 5.6